# Convert Spring Boot Actuator health status from UP/DOWN to TRUE/FALSE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a way to change the status field value from UP/DOWN

```
{"status":"UP"}
```

to TRUE/FALSE like below:

```
{"status":true}
```

I want to use the same checking logic that spring actuator is using, no customized check logic needed, only want to update the status value.

Comment: That does not even sound natural: "What is your status? true" ..... and most probably XY question

Comment: sadly that's my company's new API standard, they want to see true/false instead of UP/DOWN.

Comment: Gladly nobody has to follow that made up standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will register a new actuator endpoint `/healthy` that uses the same mechanism as the default `/health` endpoint.

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.ReadOperation;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Endpoint(id = "healthy") // Change this to expose the endpoint under a different name
public class BooleanHealthEndpoint {

    HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

    public BooleanHealthEndpoint(HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint) {
        this.healthEndpoint = healthEndpoint;
    }

    @ReadOperation
    public Health getHealth() {
        Boolean healthy = healthEndpoint.health().getStatus().equals(Status.UP);
        return new Health(healthy);
    }

    public static class Health {
        private Boolean status;

        public Health(Boolean status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public Boolean getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want to add the customized `/healthy` endpoint and continue using the default `/health` endpoint, you can add below setting in properties file, then it will be mapped to default one:

```
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=internal/health
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.healthy=/health
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Totally forgot about this question. I was able to made it work with HealthAggregator but now since this class is deprecated in newer springboot version, I had to figure out a new way and your solution absolutely works!!

Comment: Just an update to anybody who might be interest, i updated the answer with property mapping if you want to same /health endpoint as the default one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your companies new API standard was established because there's a multitude of different frameworks involved making up the range of applications and we are not talking about Spring Boot applications only (because otherwise that'd be kind irritating):

Just implement your own `@Endpoint` under `/actuator/customstatus` and aggregate all `HealthIndicator`s status' under it. You'll likely want to get inspiration from Spring Boots `HealthEndpoint` and `CompositeHealthIndicator` classes on how to do that. (topic `HealthAggregator`)